# Running Arduino IDE in terminal?

Tags: terminal

Is there any way to use Arduino in the terminal? I have a USB 802.15.4 board that works with Arduino, but I don't want to use the IDE with it, I want to use the terminal.

Comment: I think you need to explain what you mean the Arduino IDE (Integrated Development Environment) is the graphic interface

Answer (score 1):

1.) You can configure the arduino ide to use an "external editor". This means the arduino ide runs als usual but reloads the opened file for compiling and uploading. This is when you want to keep the original arduino ide.

2.) You can use the [ino projekt](http://inotool.org/) which gives you a cli interface to manage your arduino projects. The [quickstart](http://inotool.org/quickstart) guide gives a good overview of the project.

```
ino init -t blink
ino build
ino upload
ino serial
```

You can of course make all needed modifcations for differend boards and communication. I think the second option is what you are looking for ;)

Answer (score 0):

The most popular method these days is to use [arduino-builder](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-builder).

This seems to be the official Arduino command line interface now, and can do most things the IDE can do short of actually editing your code for you.

It is a set of GO scripts, so you will need GO installed.