# Write your own program to control Arduino Uno

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, ide

Is it possible to write a program to control the Arduino Uno, without using
the Arduino IDE?

Comment: Do you mean without the IDE or using other IDEs?

Comment: In addition to alternate ways to write "Arduino" programs you can also directly target the ATmega328 without using the Arduino stuff at all.  Though as a practical matter, the easiest way I've been able to ask someone got get avr-gcc and avrdude installed for such a project is to ask them to install the Arduino IDE and then look in the directory where a given version puts the compiler and flashing tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the other IDEs for Arduino?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/40/what-are-the-other-ides-for-arduino)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Arduino IDE in terminal?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/24014)

Comment: Or is the question, if it's possible to make a program on a PC, to communicate with the Arduino, without the Serial Monitor inside the Arduino IDE?

Comment: I would like to integrate the Arduino into an existing control system. Therefore I need to communicate with it without having to use / run the Arduino IDE.

Answer (score 2):

You can program the Arduino hardware without using the Arduino IDE. Using *avr-gcc* and a handful of other tools, including *make* and *avrdude*, you can compile and download to the target Aduino hardware. You can even dispense with the Arduino bootloader, and program the hardware using the common ICSP interface. To do this, you need a hardware programmer, but [you can make another Arduino into one](https://learn.adafruit.com/arduino-tips-tricks-and-techniques/arduinoisp) very easily. Using this method frees up the space used by the bootloader for your own code. Naturally, you use the editor of your choice. For a bit of a taste, have a look at the [Adafruit page on programming a trinket](https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-trinket/starting-the-bootloader?view=all#programming-with-avrdude) (technically not an Arduino, but the methods still apply).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the Arduino IDE?

Yes there are many options, for example plugins for Eclipse or Microsoft Visual Studio.

[This link](https://www.intorobotics.com/alternatives-standard-arduino-ide-one-choose/) show others like:

- CodeBender
- Electron
- Stino
- GEdit
- Komodo

Personally use normally the default Arduino IDE, but I don't like the fact you can use just a few files before it does not fit In the top bar, so than I use the Visual Studio plugin VisualMicro.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time I wrote code for arduino on codeblocks.

The other times on sublime text.

So the answer is yes.